# Modeling the distance between two point masses in space with gravity as a function of time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, space

Assume that there exist two point masses in space, an isolated system with only gravity acting. I wish to find the distance between the masses as a function of time. I have arrived at the result of $$R(t) = \frac{R_i}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{R_i^2 - (8GMt^2)/R_i},$$ where $R_i$ is the initial separation between the two objects, $G$ is the gravitational constant 6.67*10^-11, $M$ is the sum of the two masses, and $t$ is time. This function does not work for $t=0$ and some other points. Is there a better equation and/or is my function incorrect?

I will outline my work here. I first assumed, from Newton, that the two forces are $G \frac{M_1 M_2}{R^2}$ and $-G \frac{M_1 M_2}{R^2}$. Working these equations, we find the second-order nonlinear differential equation $$R'' = -\frac{GM}{R^2}.$$ The solution to this is $$R-R_i = -\sqrt{2GM(R_i-R)/RR_i}.$$ Solving for $R$ explicitly gives the above solution.

Note: I included a plus or minus in the equation because there are two cases: one wherein the distance should be greater than or equal to half the initial distance and one wherein the distance is less than half the distance. I will use this formulation for generalization to higher dimensions.

Comment: For better readability, you can use TeX-style formatting for formulas (check out the edit to see how that works). This makes it more likely that people will answer your question.

Comment: I’m virtually certain that your solution isn’t correct.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_trajectory

Answer (score 1):

(NOTE: When I started writing this response I had no idea it was going to become so long. At some point, I decided I had put in too much time to not finish it.)

I don't think this problem has an analytic solution for $R(t)$, but perhaps I'm wrong. Your expression for $\ddot{R}$ certainly looks correct, so I'm not sure where the problem is. Here is another approach.

Kepler's third law will still apply to this system:

$$\tau^2 = \frac{4\pi^2a^3}{G\left(m_1 + m_2\right)}.$$

For infalling particles, the period $\tau$ is twice the time $t_{\textrm{col}}$ needed for collision, and the semi-major axis $a$ is twice the starting separation $r_0$. So we may write

$$t_{\textrm{col}} = \pi\sqrt{\frac{r_0^3}{8GM}},$$

where $M = \left(m_1 + m_2\right)$.

In the center-of-mass frame, $m_1r_1 = m_2r_2$. If we define $\rho \equiv r_1 + r_2$, we can show after a few lines of algebra that

$$\mu\rho = m_1r_1 = m_2r_2,$$

where $\mu$ is the reduced mass:

$$\mu \equiv \frac{m_1m_2}{m_1 + m_2}.$$

Differentiate each term in the $\mu\rho$ expression to get

$$\mu\dot{\rho} = m_1\dot{r_1} = m_2\dot{r_2}.$$

We can identify $\dot{\rho}$ as $v$, $\mu v$ as the momentum of each particle, and $\frac{1}{2}\mu v^2$ as the total kinetic energy. Since mechanical energy is conserved, we may write

$$\frac{1}{2}\mu v^2 - \frac{Gm_1m_2}{\rho} = 0 - \frac{Gm_1m_2}{\rho_0}.$$

This leads to

$$v^2 = \frac{2Gm_1m_2}{\mu}\left(\frac{1}{\rho} - \frac{1}{\rho_0}\right).$$

Simplifying,

$$v = \sqrt{2G\left(m_1 + m_2\right)\left(\frac{1}{\rho} - \frac{1}{\rho_0}\right)} = \sqrt{2GM\left(\frac{1}{\rho} - \frac{1}{\rho_0}\right)}.$$

The usual approach from here is to introduce dimensionless quantities:

$$\eta \equiv \frac{\rho}{\rho_0}, \textrm{ and}$$
$$\psi \equiv \frac{t}{t_{\textrm{col}}},$$

where $t_{\textrm{col}}$ is now written as $\pi\sqrt{\rho_0^3/8GM}$. The substitutions become

$$\rho = \rho_0\eta \implies d\rho = \rho_0 d\eta, \textrm{ and}$$

$$t = t_{\textrm{col}}\psi \implies dt = t_{\textrm{col}}d\psi.$$

Since $v = -d\rho/dt$, we get

$$v = -\frac{\rho_0}{t_{\textrm{col}}}\frac{d\eta}{d\psi}.$$

Substituting for $t_{\textrm{col}}$,

$$v = -\frac{\rho_0}{\pi\sqrt{\rho_0^3/8GM}}\frac{d\eta}{d\psi} = -\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{\rho_0/8GM}}\frac{d\eta}{d\psi}.$$

Substituting into the expression for $v$ above,

$$-\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{\rho_0/8GM}}\frac{d\eta}{d\psi} = \sqrt{2GM\left(\frac{1}{\eta\rho_0} - \frac{1}{\rho_0}\right)},$$

$$\frac{d\eta}{d\psi} = -\pi\sqrt{\frac{\rho_0}{8GM}\frac{2GM}{\rho_0}\left(\frac{1}{\eta} - 1\right)},$$

$$\frac{d\eta}{d\psi} = -\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\eta} - 1\right)}.$$

Separate the variables to get

$$\frac{\pi}{2}d\psi = \frac{-d\eta}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\eta} - 1\right)}}.$$

The next step is to integrate both sides. In the center-of-mass frame coordinates, the particles fall from an initial separation distance $\rho_0 = \rho$ at $t = 0$ to $\rho = 0$ at $t = t_\textrm{col}$. So $\eta$ varies from an initial value of 1 to a final value of 0, while $\psi$ varies from an initial value of 0 to a final value of 1.

The integrals for intermediate values of $\eta$ and $\psi$ are therefore

$$\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\psi}d\psi = \int_{1}^{\eta}\frac{-d\eta}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\eta} - 1\right)}}.$$

At this point, we can switch notation to something that is more familiar. Trading $\psi$ for $t$ and $\eta$ for $r$ (just be very careful going backward from here to check the steps!), we can write

$$t\frac{\pi}{2} = \int_{1}^{r}\frac{-dr}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{r} - 1\right)}}.$$

There are probably several ways to solve the $r$ integral. I used an online tool:

$$t\frac{\pi}{2} = r\sqrt{\frac{1}{r}-1} + \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{r} - 1}\right).$$

The $\tan^{-1}$ function can probably be simplified (I have seen $\cos^{-1}$ in several sources), but I don't think there is any way to invert this to get an expression for $r$ as a function of $t$. The best we could do is get numerical solutions.

Comment: Why doesn't your solution contain an initial distance parameter? Surely this must be considered. Further, I used the same approach as you up to finding an expression for "v" or the rate of change of the distance between the two objects. I then just equated v = dR/dt and integrated. Is there a flaw with this?

Comment: In my last expression, $r$ and $t$ are still dimensionless quantities. So the initial distance parameter will always be 1.

I went back to look at your $\ddot{R}$ expression, which I initially thought was ok. But now I am not sure. Can you explain how you derived it?

If I put both particles on the $r$ axis, at positions $r_1$ and $r_2$, and let $R \equiv r_2 - r_1$, I get for the accelerations: $\vec{a_1} = \frac{Gm_2}{R^2}\hat{i}$ and $\vec{a_2} = \frac{Gm_1}{R^2}\hat{-i}$. Are you adding these? That gives $\frac{G\left(m_1 - m_2\right)}{R^2}\hat{-i},$ which does not look right.

Comment: According to Sir Isaac Newton and the coordinate system, the force on body 1 (left side) is GM1M2/R^2, and the force on body 2 (right side) is -GM1M2/R^2. For body 1, we have GM2/R^2 = a1, and for body 2 we have -GM1/R^2 = a2. a2-a1 = -G(M1+M2)/R^2 = d^2r2/dt^2 - d^2r1/dt^2 = d^2(r2-r1)/dt^2 = d^2R/dt^2. Hence, R'' = -GM/R^2, where M = M1+M2.

Comment: Yes. I have a sign error. My last expression should be $\frac{G\left(m_1 + m_2\right)}{R^2}(-\hat{r}).$ What does the negative sign mean in this expression? In the expression for $\vec{a_2}$ the negative sign means direction, but surely it cannot mean that here. If $m_2 >> m_1$, then $\ddot{R}$, if it has any geometric meaning at all, should be positive, shouldn't it? It can't mean 'decreasing'. $\ddot{R}$ should be increasing as the particles fall together. What does it mean?

Comment: The positive direction is going to the right. The negative direction is going to the left. We defined R'' to be a2-a1. This value is negative if a1 > a2. If m2 >>m1, then the acceleration on m2 will be very small (smaller than a1). Hence, it is negative. In order to talk about the actual distance/rate of change or rate of change of distance, one must take the absolute value because the above definition takes int account directions.

Comment: If we define $\ddot{R}$ as $a_2 - a_1$, and then consider the case $m_2 = m_1$, we get $\ddot{R} = 0$. $\dot{R} = 0$ also in that case. Surely that is not right. So, if the question is where your solution goes off track, I think it has something to do with the choice of coordinates and how you're defining and interpreting $R, \dot{R}$, and $\ddot{R}$.

Comment: I don’t believe this would be the case because a2 = -GM1/R^2 and a1 = GM1/R^2. Hence, a2 - a1 = -2GM1/R^2.